# How to traverse a nested frame tree by its hierarchy in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Switching into a nested iframe is no problem since you can

1. switch from the main context into a target frame
2. switch from the target frame into its child frame

But what if you want to switch from the child frame into its parent? Is there a way to do it without knowing the exact selector?

What I'm looking for is a way similar to how this is accomplished in Selenium - where you can simply tell the driver (e.g., the TestController) to switch to the parent frame. But such a thing doesn't seem to exist in TestCafe.

Answer (score 0):

At present, it possible to switch into the parent iframe window only using the following approach: switch to the main window -> navigate to target iframe. There is an [enhancement](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5429) for your use case in the TestCafe Github repository. Track this enhancement to be informed about its progress.